# Array declared as int v[100] but &(v[100]) gives no warning

Tags: c, arrays, clang, undefined-behavior

I've the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int v[100];
    int *p;

    for (p = &(v[0]); p != &(v[100]); ++p)
        if ((*p = getchar()) == EOF) {
            --p;
            break;
        }

    while (p != v)
        putchar(*--p);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output of `gcc --version` on the terminal:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Why getting the address of the element after the last of an array gives me no warning but getting for example the address of `v[101]` gives me the following warning

```
test.c:8:29: warning: array index 101 is past the end of the array (which
      contains 100 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    for(p = &(v[0]); p != &(v[101]); ++p)
                            ^ ~~~
test.c:5:5: note: array 'v' declared here
    int v[100];
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

I know that indexing elements out of the bounds of a buffer is *undefined behaviour*, so why isn't the compiler complaining about the first case?

Comment: Your program will invoke *undefined behavior* if only zero characters are read before EOF.

Comment: You should not decrement `p` upon `EOF`.

Comment: @chqrlie You say this because in the following while loop I first decrement `p` and then dereference it?

Comment: @nbro: exactly.  `p` points one past past the last valid character read with the first loop, either because you read 100 characters or because you hit the end of file. Hence do not increment `p` when you break from the first loop.  Btw this will fix the problem MikeCAT was hinting at in his comment.

Answer (score 14):

Moving pointer to one past the last element of array is allowed unless you dereference the pointer, so your program is valid if one or more characters are read before hitting EOF.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting

> The definition of the subscript operator []
>   is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators

> If the operand is the result of a unary * operator,
>   neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an
>   lvalue. Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor
>   the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator
>   were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.6 Additive operators

> Moreover, if the expression P points to the last
>   element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the
>   array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object,
>   the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object

Comment: Honestly, the citations do not answer my question. You're also saying that moving a pointer to one past the last element of an array is allowed (and the citations are not actually related to what you're saying), but I'm _also_ actually getting the address of the element past the last element (by first accessing it)...

Comment: @nbro There's also a quote that `&*X` is defined to be the same as `X`  , so when you combine this with the first quote in this answer, you see that `&v[100]` is defined to mean `(v + 100)` which is legal as per the last quote

Comment: To put it another way, talking about `*(v+100)` is only undefined if you try to access the designated memory location  (which you would do by any context other than putting `&` or `sizeof` before it)

Comment: @M.M "There's also a quote that &*X is defined to be the same as X ", where?

Comment: @nbro C11 6.5.3.2/3, "[...] if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator"

Comment: @M.M Thank you. I added that part.

Comment: [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is a draft of the C99 standard, which is *officially* obsolete. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is a draft of the C11 standard, which is current. (But it doesn't matter much for this question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I think N1256 is C99+TC3 ?

Comment: @M.M: N1256 is C99 with TCs 1, 2, and 3 merged into it. N1570 is a draft from *before* the official C11 standard, but there were no major post-N1570 changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's about compatibility with sloppily written code.

As MikeCAT cited, for an array `int ar[N]`, the expression `ar+N` is valid and results in a pointer that points to the past-the-end position. While this pointer cannot be dereferenced, it can be compared to any other pointer into the array, which allows you to write the nice `for (p = ar; p != ar+N; ++p)` loop.

Also, programmers like to write readable code, and arguably, if you want a pointer to the `i`th element of an array, writing `&ar[i]` conveys your intention more clearly than writing `ar + i`.

Combine these two, and you will get programmers who write `&ar[N]` to get the past-the-end pointer, and while this is technically accessing an invalid array index, no compiler will ever implement this as anything else than `ar + N` - in fact, the compiler would have to go out of its way to do it differently. Quite far in fact.

So, since any compiler that doesn't reason very strictly about undefined behavior will do the thing programmers expect for the expression, there's no reason not to write it, and so lots of people wrote it. And now we have massive code bases that use this idiom, which means that even modern compilers with their value tracking and reasoning about undefined behavior have to support this idiom for compatibility. And since Clang's warnings are meant to be useful, this particular warning was written so as to not warn about a case that will work anyway, out of some sense of misplaced pedantry.

Comment: *It's about compatibility with sloppily written code.* I disagree. There's nothing sloppy about constructing a pointer one past the end of an array. The behavior is well defined, and it's a useful technique.